# ImageView inside LinearLayout - wrong ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I'm trying to create item layout to RecyclerView with two main elements in ratios 20% and 80%. First element is ImageView, second is LinearLayout with some TextViews. Basically, it should look like this:

```
  20%          80%
+-----+-------------------+
| Img | Author, Date      |
+-----+ Title...          |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

So, I create layout as below, but image is always bigger than 20%.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/author"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm trying every combination of `layout_width` but always is something wrong with the ratios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: android:weightSum="5" to main layout

Comment: @Pravin unfortunately even with weightSum ImageView is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/author"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately ImageView is still too big.

Answer (score 0):

First thing put  android:weightSum="5" in parent linear layout .secondly it's not just the ratio but bitmap of image source also matters. You can use cut short your image(image resource) before setting it inside imageview.
let me know if weightsum works.

Comment: When I'm setting weightSum nothing is changed.

Comment: probably:since there is no code of image source is there : it may be image size that is having issue try using glide and put your image url in thumbnail . Also you should scale your image according to screen size and layout ratio.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing to give `weightSum` to parent Layout.
just add weightSum to main Layout in your case `LinearLayout`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">
```

Comment: unfortunately even with weightSum ImageView is too big.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have understood that you want to create a list row then you need to fix the height of layout and image view as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/author"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```